# GWAS array to matrix

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, gwas

(this will be a supposition because the number are higher but to make things easier)

Imagine that you have genotyped 10 persons and you have 3  SNIPS each one with 2 alels. then you end up with a matrix like this:

, , 1

|  | [,1] | [,2] | [,3] | [,4] | [,5] | [,6] | [,7] | [,8] | [,9] | [,10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| [2,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

, , 2

|  | [,1] | [,2] | [,3] | [,4] | [,5] | [,6] | [,7] | [,8] | [,9] | [,10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| [2,] | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

, , 3

|  | [,1] | [,2] | [,3] | [,4] | [,5] | [,6] | [,7] | [,8] | [,9] | [,10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| [2,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

---

I would transform my array and put:
something like:

- if there are two 0 on the same column then is a 0.
- if there is a 0 and a 1 then is a 1.
- if there is a 1 and a 0 then is a 1.
- if there are two 1 then is a 2.

I think is more easy to understand with visually.

, , 1

|  | [,1] | [,2] | [,3] | [,4] | [,5] | [,6] | [,7] | [,8] | [,9] | [,10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

, , 2

|  | [,1] | [,2] | [,3] | [,4] | [,5] | [,6] | [,7] | [,8] | [,9] | [,10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

, , 3

|  | [,1] | [,2] | [,3] | [,4] | [,5] | [,6] | [,7] | [,8] | [,9] | [,10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

---

And then transform it into a matrix like this (persons x SNIPS)

|  | [,1] | [,2] | [,3] | [,4] | [,5] | [,6] | [,7] | [,8] | [,9] | [,10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| [2,] | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| [3,] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I usually use R but if someone do this with pyton i can handle it. If someone can help me it will be really helpfull. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `colSums` on margin 3.

```
t(apply(A, 3, colSums))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1    1    2    0    2    0     0
# [2,]    2    0    1    1    1    2    0    2    0     0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    2    0     0
```

---

*Data:*

```
A <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dim = c(2L, 
10L, 3L))
```